# Find all digits a,b,c,d such that a|bcd, b|cda, c|dab, d|abc (where the right hand side represents the decimal representation of a 3 digit number)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

This was a problem from a local junior competition neither I nor anyone I could find the solution for. I didn't get any real progress.

Comment: "digits" include $0$?   In any case, please edit to include your efforts.  Have you found any examples other than the ones with all $4$ digits equal?

Comment: For what it's worth I have found exactly two non-trivial examples (well, up to permutations).  Maybe there are others, maybe not.

Comment: Ah, found an even less trivial one and another in the same line as the first two.  Not sure how to make much progress without searching.

Comment: @lulu Can zero actually divide anything?  In any case, if any digit is even, it appears every digit is even.  And assuming 0 isn't allowed, if one digit is 5, they're all 5.  Test examples from there?

Comment: @Mike  Yeah, I figure $0$ is out for the reason you said.  As to constructing the examples, well $(1,9,7,1)$ works which looks pretty random really.  I found that one through brute searching (though it makes sense to look at examples like $(1,1,1,3)$ with many $1's$).

Comment: In any case, I am voting to close this for lack of effort from the OP.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions trivially contain $(1,1,1,1)$ and its multiples up to $9$ times. It should also be known at a contest level that in base $b$, numbers' digitwise sums and digital roots (recursive sums until only a single digit remains) conserve parity modulo all proper divisors of $b-1$, so $111$ is a multiple of $3$, and this also has multiples $(2,2,2,6)$ and $(3,3,3,9)$ without overflow. However, there also exists $(1,1,9,7)$, which I'm not sure how you'd go about finding.

Program proof: (Note that though solutions are considered invariant under cyclic shift, it is small enough that we need not employ Duval's algorithm :-)

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> tuple(sorted(set(map(lambda t: min(map(lambda i: t[i:]+t[:i],range(4))),filter(lambda t: all(map(lambda i: (lambda a,b,c,d: a and not((b*100+c*10+d)%a))(*t[i:],*t[:i]),range(4))),product(range(10),repeat=4))))))
((1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1, 3), (1, 1, 9, 7), (2, 2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 2, 6), (3, 3, 3, 3), (3, 3, 3, 9), (4, 4, 4, 4), (5, 5, 5, 5), (6, 6, 6, 6), (7, 7, 7, 7), (8, 8, 8, 8), (9, 9, 9, 9))
```